# Issue retrieving list object has no attribute input

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer

I have the following code removing some layer from the start of a model, I getting error on input shape

```
import keras
from keras import layers, models,Input
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Conv2D

vgg_model=applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet')
layers = [l for l in vgg_model.layers]
layer_input_shape=layers.Input(batch_shape=model.get_layer('input_1').
get_input_shape_at(0))
x=layer_input_shape
for i in range(3, len(layers)):
  layers[i].trainable = False
  x = layers[i](x)
result_model = Model(inputs=layers[0].input, outputs=x)
result_model.summary()


img='/content/test.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img, target_size=(224, 224))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)
preds = result_model.predict(x)
print('Predicted:', decode_predictions(preds, top=3)[0])
```

error

```
--> 25 layer_input_shape=layers.Input(batch_shape=model.get_layer('input_1').get_input_shape_at(0))
 AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'Input'
```

Comment: Please notice that any code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant to the issue (never executed), and it should not be included here as it just creates unnecessary clutter (edited out). Be sure to always include the full error trace (see [mcve]).

Comment: What is layers.Input supposed to be?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, Thank you for your input I have updated the post

Comment: But that does not answer my question.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, the first layer output is the input

Comment: No, I am talking about this part: layers.Input(batch_shape=model.get_layer('input_1').get_input_shape_at(0)), where is layers.Input in here? Are you trying to reference the Input class in tf.keras.layers?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, no I am not trying to reference the input class in tf.keras.layers

Comment: Then what is this code trying to do? which class are you trying to reference here? (Maybe keras.layers.Input?)

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy using from keras import layers, models

Comment: But you also have a variable called layers, this overwrites your imports.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, thanks how would I solve it than

Comment: use keras.layers.Input